# Building Python Pandas DataFrames from scratch (i.e. storing the results of calculations in a DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’d like to store results from various calculations in a Pandas DataFrame. The results are computed from a series of time-series (daily time step) data files. Each data file's name will be index (or key) in the in the DataFrame. Initially the DataFrame will be an empty table. The first set of results will be stored in the DataFrame as they are computed. Subsequently results will be to be added to the DataFrame by the key. Eg.:

1. Initialize an empty DataFrame with the columns: key, count, std, mean, min, 25%, 50%, 75%, max, Skew, Kurtosis, SACF, Jarquebera, JBTest, and KSTest (the DataFrame.describe() attributes and a few new columns that will be computed).
2. Load a file with the names of the datasets.
3. Iterate through the datasets, by name, computing the DataFrame.describe() for several columns in the datasets.
4. Iterate through the datasets by name computing Skew, Kurtosis, SACF, Jarquebera, JBTest, and KSTest for several columns in the datasets (basically #3 with additional computations).
5. Store the results form step #3 and 4 in the DataFrame by the file name, which is synanons with the key.
6. Store the results in an Excel file.

I can do everything except step #5. Any thoughts on how to do this? It seemed simple enough when I started as I thought it would be simply defining the DataFrame and then adding the computed results to the DataFrame. It’s been anything but easy. Everything I’ve tried has failed. Been trying to figure out #5 for days without any success. Obviously, I don’t understand DataFrames very well, so any resources you can point me to would be helpful. While I’ve learned quite a lot about manipulating an existing DataFrame, building one from scratch has befuddled me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm, sounds like Step 5 should be relatively simple, something like `df.loc[key, [col1, col2, col3]] = [val1, val2, val3]`. Would you be able to post a runnable example, with sample data and the code that performs the other steps?